# Upper bound on $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm of the inverse of a sparse matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, condition-number

Suppose that I have a sparse and invertible $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $M$ such that $M$ has at most $k$ non-zero entries ($k<<n$) in any row or column. (The case I'm interested in is $k=6$).

One can show that for any matrix $M$ we have
$$\|M^{-1}\|_2\leq \frac{\|M\|_2^{n-1}}{|\det(M)|}\tag{$*$}\label{*} $$

1. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the absolute values of smallest and largest *non-zero* entries in $M$ respectively. Can I use \eqref{*} to get a bound on $\|M^{-1}\|_2$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?
2. Is \eqref{*} tight? Might there be another way to bound $\|M^{-1}\|_2?$

In fact, $M$ has more properties, but are a bit tedious to write down.
In case the above information is not sufficient, please let me know in the comments so that I update the question.

Comment: Note that with $k=6$, $M$ can only be invertible if $n \leq 6$. If $M$ is invertible with $k = n = 6$, then $M$ must be expressible in the form $M = DP$ where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is a permutation matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann why so? The identity matrix has at most $k=6$ non-zero elements in each row or column but is invertible. Did you mean to say if $M$ has *exactly* 6 non-zero entries?

Comment: @demilevi The identity matrix fits the description: take $D = I$ and $P = I$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann My point is that $n$ need not be $\leq 6$ for $M$ to be invertible. Clearly, an $n\times n$ identity matrix is symmetric and has at most $k=6$ entries in any row/column and is invertible. So I don't understand why *"with $k=6$, $M$ can only be invertible if $n\leq 6$"*.

Comment: I missed that it was $k$ entries "in any row or column"; I thought it was the number of entries in the entire matrix